# Application Insights Telemetry Metrics

Tags: paas, app-insight

Sitecore 9 on Azure PaaS comes with App Insights as a default. Out of the box, there are a bunch of metrics captured. This counts for a lot of data that comes at a cost. Even a clean install with no traffic reaches the default daily cap. This can be increased but comes at a cost.

Sitecore wrote an article https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/sitecore_on_azure/analytics/configure_application_insights_post_deployment to describe how to tweak you app insights.

I would like to reduce the metrics being measured under the counterLoader/includedCounters node. Does someone have experience with this? Which metrics are actually usefull and should definitly be retained, which one are more nice to haves? I know this is can depend on the kind of project but if there are any general guidelines, I would welcome them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never seen a list with usefull metrics. I discussed with Azure Team few months ago and they mention me to disabled GetChangesAvgTime counter.

One specific counter, GetChangesAvgTime, logged multiple times a second that can be disabled. It is related to change tracking on XDB search index worker.

To disable this specific counter please follow next steps:

1. Edit file on XP0 XConnect role or XP1 collectionsearch role
   **\App_data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_data\Diagnostics\Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Counters.json**
2. Find the specific counter (231) GetChangesAvgTime and (232) GetChangeAvgTimeBase.
3. Remove or comment out the following lines

   ```
   {

    "CounterIndex": 231,

    "CounterName": "GetChangesAvgTime",

    "CounterDescription": "Get Changes average time elapsed time in milliseconds",

   "CounterType": "AverageCount64"

   },

   {

   "CounterIndex": 232,

   "CounterName": "GetChangesAvgTimeBase",

   "CounterDescription": "Get Changes average time elapsed time in milliseconds Base",

    "CounterType": "AverageBase"

    }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the info Vlad. I have checked telemetry in azure portal. I have indeed a lot of metric info on counterindex 231. I don't have any data on the 232. I reviewed all those metrics and found that counter indexes 270, 272 and 274 also have the same amount of telemetry entries as the 231.

Answer (score 1):

Just expanding on Vlad's answer in light of new information - in Sitecore 9.1.0 they have removed a fair few counters.  In comparison with 9.0.2 they have removed:

**Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Counters.json**

- 228, 229, 232, 233, 270 to 275

**Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Counters.json**

- 2118 - 2121
- However they have added a few dozen too here.

**Sitecore.Cloud.ApplicationInsights.config**

- No changes to the counters although they have made it much easier to disable all application insights telemetry - this can be done via web.config.